# A universal model?

Tags: word-choice

I'm doing research on wind speed and direction modelling.
For previous models, people need different models for wind speed, and direction, and they need to be fitted independently.

Now I'm proposing a **universal model**. That is, it takes into wind speed and direction at the same time, so it can both model the wind speed, direction and the joint distribution of wind speed and direction.

I want to know, how can I call this model?

Now I call it universal model, since it applies to wind speed and direction. but is it proper? I feel that a universal model may more toward that the model can be applied to different locations, circumstances etc., and my naming is inproper.

Or **holistic model**?

Comment: How about *a unified model* - modeled after https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_field_theory

Comment: _Multi-model_ ?

Comment: Not an answer in a linguistic sense, but it sounds as if you have discovered _vectors_. They're not new, even in meteorology - I regularly see weather reports using them: arrows on a map indicating wind speed _and_ direction.

Comment: @oerkelens yes, it's essentially vector. The problem is that most people don't model wind speed and direction using vector, for they don't know what model to use. And that's one of the highlight of my research.

Answer (score 1):

A **combined** model incorporating both the speed and direction of wind.